# Swift Button Array

Tags: arrays, swift, button, iboutlet, iboutletcollection

In a **Swift + SQLite** project I'm trying to populate an array of 4 buttons in my UI with a SQL query. The best I could do so far is as the code below shows, but I'm sure it can be done in a cleaner way. I tried to do both the SQL query result reading and button change in the same loop but got all sorts of **type mismatch and reference errors**.
 Any suggestion will be much appreciated.

```
var answerText: Array<String?> = ["","","",""]

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet  var answerButton: Array<UIButton> = []

func displayQuestion(questionNumber: Int){

    let querySQL = "SELECT answer FROM answers WHERE answers.question = '\(questionNumber)'"
    let results:FMResultSet? = myDatabase.executeQuery(querySQL,
        withArgumentsInArray: nil)
    var j=0
    while results?.next() == true {
        answerText[j] = results?.stringForColumn("answer")
       j=j+1
    }
    j=0
    for item in  answerButton{
        var button:UIButton = item as UIButton
        button.setTitle(answerText[j], forState: UIControlState.Normal)
        j=j+1
    }
  }   
 }
```

Comment: can you explain more about it???????

Comment: What happens if your SQL query takes a long time ? Then I expect your results to be empty while the rest of your code executes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are getting reference error because you are declaring an array as a IBoutlet . if your **answerButton** having objects of UIButton than that should not be **@IBOutlet  var answerButton: Array = []**.
answerButton declared like this  **var answerButton: Array = []**.

please modify below code according to you code  if you want to test the below code than just copy and past it into func viewDidLoad() of your viewcontroller and this will show you four buttons on you view

```
       var answerText: Array<String?> = ["Button1","Button2","Button3","Button4"]

     var answerButton: Array<UIButton> = []

    for var i = 0; i<=answerText.count; i++ {

        var button = UIButton.buttonWithType(.System) as! UIButton

        button.titleLabel!.font = UIFont.systemFontOfSize(12)

        button.titleLabel!.lineBreakMode = .ByTruncatingTail

        var numberOfButton = 5
        let j = i
        var y:CGFloat  = (CGFloat)(j*690/(numberOfButton+1)-21);
        button.frame.size.height = 42
        button.frame.size.width = 150
        button.frame.origin.y = y
        button.frame.origin.x = 250.0
        answerButton .insert(button, atIndex: i)

    }

for var i = 0; i<answerText.count; i++ {

        var button:UIButton = answerButton [i]

        button.setTitle(answerText[i], forState: UIControlState.Normal)

      self.view .addSubview(button)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var buttons: [UIButton?] {
    return [self.firstButton, self.secondButton, self.thirdButton]
}
```

Comment: Some explanation what this code does and how it solves the problem would be nice.